# Ruby GET response body encoded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-get

Hey I am trying to get an API request working but somehow the Ruby GET messes it up. I'm running the app in a docker container and when I use curl inside the container it returns the correct value. This is my code:

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @group = Group.find(params[:statistic_group_id])
    @devices = @group.devices
    pids = @devices.map{|d| d.hwg['pid']}.uniq
    pid = {'pid' => pids}
    get(pid)
  end

  def get(params)

    require 'net/http' 
    require 'uri'

    password = "something"
    user =  "something"

    url = URI( "something").tap do |uri|
        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    end
    https = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, use_ssl: url.scheme == 'https')
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
    request.basic_auth(user, password)
    response = https.request(request)
    @body = response.body
  end
end
```

"\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\x8A\x8E\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0003\u0000)\xBBL\r\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000" This is what I get as response.body. The response header is 200 (so it should be fine?)

This is what I should get [] (empty json array). The url seems to be created successfully (because it works when I paste it from the console if I execute the commands one by one). I honestly have no idea what could be going wrong.

Edit:
The problem was that the Ruby default encoding overwrote encoding headers sent in the response. This can be fixed by adding "Accept-Encoding"

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding' => 'utf-8')
```

Comment: What's the response content type?

Comment: response.body.encode('utf-8')

Comment: @snake encode doesn't actually work here, because it was gzipped by Ruby.

Comment: @Gowtham the response type matches the one I expect. The problem was that the default Ruby encoding overwrote the encoding headers sent in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your response is gzipped.

Comment: Thank you that was indeed it. My colleague helped me find the solution. The problem is Ruby goes to their own encoding (part of which is gzip) when none is specified in the request (even though a utf-8 header is sent in response).